# Carga de controladores, método y parámetro en MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Muy buenas tardes caballeros, tengo un pequeño problema con una estructura MVC, lo que sucede es que cuando intento mandar los datos para hacer una inserción en la base de datos por mi controlador el hace el proceso normal de inserción , pero el problema consiste en que también manda **DATOS VACÍOS** si no le asigno nada en el formulario y eso es malo, ya se que me dirán que valide con **empty ()** y con **isset()**  pero el problema es que cuando asigno un condicional con empty el me salta ese condicional y me lo envía a mis modelos de igual forma.

ejemplo sencillo con codigo

```
introducir el código aquí
<a href="paginas/agregar">
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta mi MVC trabaja de la siguiente forma

- 1-Parametro que paso es el **controlador** => Paginas
- 2-Parametro que paso es el **metodo** => Agregar
- 3-Parametro que paso ya es el id o valor => en este caso es vacio
- seria algo asi **carpeta_raiz/mi_controlador/mi_metodo/mi_valor**

En este orden de ideas esa información llega aquí

```
introducir el código aquí
public function agregar()
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            $datos = [
                'nombre' => trim($_POST['nombre']),        
                'email' => trim($_POST['email']),        
                'telefono' => trim($_POST['telefono'])
            ];
        if($this->usuarioModelo->agregarUsuario($datos)){
            redireccionar('/paginas');
        }else{
            die('Algo salio mal');
        }
    }else{
        $datos = [
            'nombre' => '',
            'email' => '',
            'telefono' => ''
        ];
        $this->vista('paginas/agregar', $datos);
    }
}
```

Donde yo valido si se envía por **$POST** y si no le asigno a mi **array** que tiene datos **vacíos** y envió esos datos a la vista para que no muera la **ejecución**,
después a si es correcto los datos serán pasados a un **array asociativo** el cual eliminara caracteres de espacio etc, y después llamara el **modelo** que hará la correspondiente inserción , si este retorna **true** significa que se realizo la consulta, y si devuelve **false** se detiene la ejecución del **script**, pero le he insertando de muchas formas para validarlo cuando este vacio y nada sigue insertando de igual forma.

y por ultimo este es el modelo

```
introducir el código aquí
public function agregarUsuario($datos)//Aqui recibo los datos
{
    return $this->db->agregar($datos);        
}
```

Nota:Basta de mas decir que se encuentran en clases y que todo en el modelo hago la instancia de mi conexión.

Este es el formulario que envía la información respectiva a mis controladores

```
introducir el código aquí
<form action="<?php echo RUTA_URL;?>paginas/agregar/" method="POST">
    <label for="nombre">
     Nombre:<input type="text" placeholder="Digite nombre" name="nombre">
    </label>
    <label for="email">
    Email:<input type="email" placeholder="Digite email" name="email">
    </label>
    <label for="telefono">
 Telefono:<input type="text" placeholder="Digite telefono" name="telefono">
    </label>
     <input type="submit" value="Agregar Usuario">
</form>
```

**Nota Importante**:Cabe destacar que la constante **RUTA_URL** pasa por todo el proyecto y es la raíz del mismo por eso le puse después paginas/agregar/ porque el controlador detecta después de la url de la constante los métodos y mis controladores

Comment: podes agregar el formulario que envia los datos ?

Comment: Ya lo agregue al final del formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te aconsejaría de poner como `required` los campos del formulario, para evitar que se envíe con datos vacios  :

```
<form action="<?php echo RUTA_URL;?>paginas/agregar/" method="POST">
    <label for="nombre">
        Nombre:<input type="text" placeholder="Digite nombre" name="nombre" required >
    </label>
    <label for="email">
        Email:<input type="email" placeholder="Digite email" name="email" required >
    </label>
    <label for="telefono">
        Telefono:<input type="text" placeholder="Digite telefono" name="telefono" required >
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Agregar Usuario">
</form>
```

para controlar que no te manden datos vacios podrías ayudarte con una expresión regular echa en Javascript para restringir los caracteres
ejemplo :

```js
function filtro(input){
   var regex = /^\s/gi;
   input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo RUTA_URL;?>paginas/agregar/" method="POST">
    <label for="nombre">
     Nombre:<input  placeholder="Digite nombre" id="nombre" name="nombre"onkeyup="filtro(this)" required>
    </label>
    <label for="email">
    Email:<input type="email" placeholder="Digite email" name="email" required>
    </label>
    <label for="telefono">
 Telefono:<input  placeholder="Digite telefono" name="telefono" id="telefono" onkeyup="filtro(this)" required >
    </label>
     <input type="submit" value="Agregar Usuario">
</form>
```

lo que hace este javascript es no permitir que el contenido empieza con un espacio, ósea que minimo un carácter lleva

**EDIT**

entonces probaría a hacer algo por el estilo, momentaneamente es lo unico que se me ocurre :

```
 if(!empty($_POST['nombre'] || !empty($_POST['email'] || !empty($_POST['telefono']){
    $datos = [
        'nombre' => trim($_POST['nombre']),        
        'email' => trim($_POST['email']),        
        'telefono' => trim($_POST['telefono'])
    ];
    if($this->usuarioModelo->agregarUsuario($datos)){
        redireccionar('/paginas');
    }

}
```

espero que te sea de ayuda, éxitos

Comment: No creo que sea buena practica hacer validaciones del lado del cliente, lo mejor seria hacerlo en el controlador y si hay un vacío retornar un error a la vista podria ser con ajax para no refrescar la pagina

Comment: Amigo muchísimas gracias por tomarte la molestia de revisar mi pregunta pero es que el problema de hacer una validación con javascript es que si el usuario es un poco mas experimentado modificara el formulario dando click derecho inspeccionar elemento y borrara la validación, y por si fuera poco si no funciona desactiva javascript del navegador y ya quedo sin validación por eso necesito hacerlo con php.

Comment: De eso hablo Igmer Rodriguez necesito hacerla del lado del servidor, en el backend para que sea mas segura.